# Oracle Database Vault: Changing DV Owner and DV Account-Manager passwords hangs PX Deq: Execute Reply/row cache lock

Tags: oracle, security, oracle-19c

When changing the password of the users mentioned above the sessions hangs. And it seems to be a deadlock. When changing the password it seems that two sessions are spawned:

```
Blocking session
C##DVAM_ROOT
1 26 58821  Concurrency row cache lock
Waiting session:
C##DVAM_ROOT
0 405 45629 fuvf4b27452y5 Idle PX Deq: Execute Reply


fuvf4b27452y5 -> /* SQL Analyze(405,0) */
SELECT /*+PARALLEL(1) NO_STATEMENT_QUEUING */ *
FROM X$KXFTASK /*kpdbReplayDDL,PDB_Replay_DDL*/
```

When an user with with dv_patch_admin role changes the password it works. When disabling Database Vault it works.
I didn’t find this in oracle support.
This is an Oracle Database 19.9 Multitenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We opened a SR at Oracle support. It was identified as a bug and forwarded to development.

Workarounds:

1. Give DV_PATCH_ADMIN role to user changing pwd.
2. Close pdb and execute in cdb.